# Refresh current activity in Xamarin

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, xamarin, refresh

I am new to Xamarin and I am trying to refresh my `MainActivity` from itself. I read a lot of forums about that but I still can't find any solution. My problem is that I need to do the refreshing from another method, not within the `onCreate()` method.

My `MainActivity` is a `listview` and I want to reload the whole activity in order to refresh the listview. I need to reload the whole activity because in my situation I can't use `NotifyDataSetChanged()` because the changes I am making to the `listview` are not within the `onCreate()` method and not in a new activity neither. I have a CAB menu from where the user has the option to delete selected note from the listview. I am using the `NotifyDataSetChanged()` method in my `onResume()` method and it's working perfectly when I am making the changes to my `listview` in another activity but it's not working when I am making them from the current activity because then the `onResume()` method is not being called .

I've tried doing it like this:

```
Intent refresh = new Intent(this,typeof(MainActivity));
refresh.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NoAnimation);
Finish();
StartActivity(refresh);
```

but it's giving me `NullPointerException` on the first row already .. And the exception I think is the "this". So I tried it differently : instead of using "this" I am using - `Intent refresh = new Intent(context ,typeof(MainActivity));` where context=this in the `onCreate()` method. But in this way it's still giving me a `NullPointerException` but this time on the row - `StartActivity(refresh)` ..

Thanks in advance ! :)

Comment: `NotifyDataSetChanged` most definitely works outside of the `OnCreate`/`OnResume` overrides.

Comment: Yes, it works, but I have initialized my adapter within the onCreate method .. And I don't know how to use it outside the onCreate() method .

Comment: See my answer, it's a small example, but will work.

Answer (score 0):

`NotifyDataSetChanged()` most definitely works outside of the `OnCreate`/`OnResume`, etc overrides

If you want to use `NotifyDataSetChanged()`, you will need to change the items in the `ListAdapter` that is linked to the `ListView`.

Something like this

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
   [Activity]
   public MyActivity : Activity
   {

      private ArrayAdapter<string> myAdapter = null;

      public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
      {
            myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(); //or whatever type your adapter is.
            myListView.Adapter = myAdapter; 
      }

      private void UpdateList()
      {
            //Delete item
            myAdapter.Remove(item);

            //Insert item
            myAdapter.Insert(item, 0); //0 = position for new item

            //Add item
            myAdapter.Add(item);

            myAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: yes but if I want to use myAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged() in other method than onCreate() then you are gonna have NullPointerException .. Because even the way you are doing it you are instantiate the adapter within the onCreate() ..

Comment: No, because it is a global (scope of the class) field, it will not be null.

Comment: Can you show your code, as I have done this all over with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

Thisi is the code:

```
    public List<DeliveryNoteInfo> _lstNoteInfo = new List<DeliveryNoteInfo>();
    public ObjectToSerialize objectToSerialize;
    public Serializer serializer;
    private ListView objListItem;
    private MonoBaseAdapter2 myAdapter = null;
    static AlertDialog levelDialog;
    static string[] items;
    static Context context2;

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle SavedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate (SavedInstanceState);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
        // Get our UI controls from the loaded layout
        Button addButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.AddButton);
        addButton.Click += delegate {
            StartActivity (typeof(AddActivity));
        };
        Button sortButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.SortButton);
        sortButton.Click += delegate {
            ShowSortDialog(_lstNoteInfo);
        };
        Button exitButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.ExitButton);
        exitButton.Click += delegate {
            Finish();
        };
        context2 = this;
        // Loading the already saved notes from external file
        objectToSerialize = new ObjectToSerialize();
        serializer = new Serializer ();
        var path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
        if (System.IO.File.Exists (path + "outputFile.txt")) {
            deserialize ();
        }
        //Displaying the Notes in a custom made ListView 
        objListItem = FindViewById<ListView> (Resource.Id.listView1);
        myAdapter = new MonoBaseAdapter2 (this, _lstNoteInfo);
        objListItem.Adapter = myAdapter;
        objListItem.FastScrollEnabled = true;
        objListItem.ChoiceMode = (ChoiceMode)AbsListViewChoiceMode.MultipleModal;
        objListItem.SetMultiChoiceModeListener (new CabMenu(this,this,objListItem));


        objListItem.ItemClick += delegate(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e) {
            var itemClicked = new Intent(this,typeof(InfoActivity));
            itemClicked.PutExtra("File name",_lstNoteInfo[e.Position].ImageID);
            itemClicked.PutExtra("Date",_lstNoteInfo[e.Position].Date);
            itemClicked.PutExtra("Type",_lstNoteInfo[e.Position].Type);
            itemClicked.PutExtra("Name",_lstNoteInfo[e.Position].Name);
            itemClicked.PutExtra("Supplier",_lstNoteInfo[e.Position].Supplier);
            itemClicked.PutExtra("Amount",_lstNoteInfo[e.Position].Amount);
            itemClicked.PutExtra("Info",_lstNoteInfo[e.Position].AddInfo);
            StartActivity (itemClicked);
        };

    }

    protected override void OnResume ()
    {
        base.OnResume ();
        var lstNoteInfo = new List<DeliveryNoteInfo>();
        var path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
        if (System.IO.File.Exists (path + "outputFile.txt")) {
            objectToSerialize = serializer.DeSerializeObject ("outputFile.txt");
            lstNoteInfo = objectToSerialize.DeliveryNoteInfo;
        }
        _lstNoteInfo.Clear ();
        _lstNoteInfo.AddRange (lstNoteInfo);
        ((MonoBaseAdapter2)objListItem.Adapter).NotifyDataSetChanged ();
        objListItem.Invalidate ();
        ((MonoBaseAdapter2)objListItem.Adapter).NotifyDataSetInvalidated ();

    }

    public void makeNote (String fileName, String finalDate, String type,String noteName, String amount, String supplier, String addInfo)
    {
        _lstNoteInfo.Add (new DeliveryNoteInfo (){ ImageID = fileName, Date = finalDate,Type = type, Name = noteName, Amount = amount, Supplier = supplier, AddInfo = addInfo});
        objectToSerialize.DeliveryNoteInfo = _lstNoteInfo;
        serializer.SerializeObject("outputFile.txt", objectToSerialize);
        Console.WriteLine ("Name: " + noteName);
        Console.WriteLine ("Amount: " + amount);
    }
    public void RefreshAfterDelete(List<DeliveryNoteInfo> updatedList)
    {
        _lstNoteInfo.Clear ();
        _lstNoteInfo.AddRange (updatedList);
        objectToSerialize.DeliveryNoteInfo = _lstNoteInfo;
        serializer.SerializeObject("outputFile.txt", objectToSerialize);
        UpdateList ();
    }
    public void PrintCollection<T>(IEnumerable<T> col)
    {
        foreach(var item in col)
            System.Console.WriteLine("ITEM"); 
    }
    void deserialize ()
    {
        objectToSerialize = serializer.DeSerializeObject ("outputFile.txt");
        _lstNoteInfo = objectToSerialize.DeliveryNoteInfo;
    }
    void deserialize(List<DeliveryNoteInfo> list)
    {
        objectToSerialize = serializer.DeSerializeObject ("outputFile.txt");
        list = objectToSerialize.DeliveryNoteInfo;
    }
    void serialize (List<DeliveryNoteInfo> list)
    {
        objectToSerialize.DeliveryNoteInfo = list;
        serializer.SerializeObject("outputFile.txt", objectToSerialize);
    }
    private void ShowSortDialog(List<DeliveryNoteInfo> updatedList)
    {

        // Strings to Show In Dialog with Radio Buttons
        items = new string[]{" Date "," Name "," Type of delivery "," Supplier "};

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.SetTitle("Sort by ..");
        builder.SetSingleChoiceItems(items, -1,  onClick);
        levelDialog = builder.Create();
        levelDialog.Show();
    }
    public void onClick(object sender, DialogClickEventArgs e) {
        var item = (int) e.Which;
        List<DeliveryNoteInfo> list = new List<DeliveryNoteInfo> (); 
        switch(item)
        {
        case 0:
            // Your code when first option seletced
            Console.WriteLine ("Sorting by date..");
            break;
        case 1:
            //  Sorting by name
            objectToSerialize = serializer.DeSerializeObject ("outputFile.txt");
            list = objectToSerialize.DeliveryNoteInfo;
            List<DeliveryNoteInfo> SortedList = list.OrderBy (o => o.Name).ToList ();
            RefreshAfterDelete (SortedList);
            Console.WriteLine ("Sorting by name..");
            break;
        case 2:
            // Your code when 3rd option seletced
            Console.WriteLine ("Sorting by type of delivery..");
            break;
        case 3:
            // Your code when 4th  option seletced  
            Console.WriteLine ("Sorting by supplier ..");
            break;

        }
        levelDialog.Dismiss();    
    }
    private void ListClicked (object sender, DialogClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder (this);
        builder.SetMessage (string.Format ("You selected: {0} , {1}", (int)e.Which, items [(int)e.Which]));

        builder.Show ();
    }
    private void UpdateList()
    {
      myAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `objListItem` also null in that method?

Comment: If I try doing it like this : 
((MonoBaseAdapter2)objListItem.Adapter).NotifyDataSetChanged ();  it is still giving me [NullReferenceException], hence it's also null ..

Comment: I noticed now, I use a `ListActivity` and not a normal `Activity`.

Comment: So do you have any idea how to make it works in my situation ? I am struggling with this for so long already and I am start getting crazy !

Comment: Seeing as you are holding onto a static instance of the context (will eventually cause memory leaks), you can hold onto a static instance of your list adapter.